# Can I express an accessor (getter/setter) as a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way of expressing that an object *has* to have accessors through TypeScript's type system?

Take this function:

```
replaceUsingAccessor<T, TKey extends keyof T, R extends T[TKey] = T[TKey]>(obj: T, prop: TKey, replacement: R): R;
```

This method says it has will accept `obj` and will replace any of its fields using the `replacement`. The problem is that it accepts both

`{ a: 1}` as well as the equivalent

```
{
  _val: 1,
  set a(val){ this._val = a; },
  get a(){ return this._val; }
}
```

whereas I would like to restrict the signature to only accept the latter.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `get/set` to describe accessors

```
type A = {
  value: number
}
type B = {
  get value(): number
  set value(v: number);
}
```

but they cannot be destinguished from just values

Comment: > they cannot be destinguished from just values

does that mean objects of type A can be assigned to type B

Comment: @oligofren yes and more then that, if you have two values you can't know which one it is (like you e.g. can see `{a:1}` vs `{readonly a:1}`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77416310/infer-set-accessor-type