# Infer set accessor type

Tags: typescript

How to infer set accessor type in a type with different-typed get and set?

```
type B = {
  get value(): number
  set value(v: string);
}
type InferGetSet<B> = { get: number, set: string }
```

The straigntforward way doesn't work:

```
type Fail1<B> = B extends {
  get value(): infer G,
  set value(v: infer S)
} ? { get: G, set: S } : never
type f1 = Fail1<B>
//   ^?
// { get: number, set: unknown } - fail
type Fail2<B> = {
  get: B extends { get value(): infer V } ? V : never,
  set: B extends { set value(v: infer V) } ? V : never,
}
type f2 = Fail2<B>
//   ^?
// { get: number, set: number } - fail
```

Comment: Not the DV, but that does seem like a slightly odd thing to want: a property where the getter and setter have a different type. I can think of cases where that *might* be useful, but do you mind expanding on yours? Also it's not really clear what you're asking for here. Is something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeAoKUDmFhQG4EMAbAVwgAoBKALigDtiBbAIwgCc0oBnbPI0s3DU7BWAS1oYKAbhQBfFCgDGAe1rCoAM2XKacRKnRYcBEuQrIorbMVa0oAViiyANB27G+5TuaRQVa5UIIADpCZQwyTmCrSHxgSnN5eSA) your problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JaredSmith I want to extract setter type (or to be exact to *know* how to do it as I don't have a place to use it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to infer both `get` and `set` types of a property. The problem is that whenever trying to infer property types of a variant accessor TypeScript will always give you the type that you *read* (`get`) and not the type that you *write* (`set`).

This behavior has been mentioned in some issues such as [microsoft/TypeScript#53594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53594) but isn't very well documented as it seems.

> **Divergent Getters and Setters**
>
> - [...]
> - Indexed access types?
>
>   - T[keyof T]?
>   - Read types or write types?
>   - We always pick the read types.

---

This also explains why in your `Fail2` example `f2` is inferred as `{ get: number, set: number }`. Both properties are of type `number` altough `set` in type `B` takes a `string`.

```
type B = {
  get value(): number
  set value(v: string);
}

type Fail2<B> = {
  get: B extends { get value(): infer V } ? V : never,
  set: B extends { set value(v: infer V) } ? V : never,
}
type f2 = Fail2<B>
//   ^?
// { get: number, set: number } - fail
```